# Histogram intersection kernel optimization in MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, classification, svm

I want to try a svm classifier using histogram intersection kernel, for a dataset of 153 images but it takes a long time. This is my code:

```
a = load('...'); %vectors
b = load('...'); %labels
g = dataset(a,b);

error = crossval(g,libsvc([],proxm([],'ih'),100),10,10);
error1 = crossval(g,libsvc([],proxm([],'ih'),10),10,10);
error2 = crossval(g,libsvc([],proxm([],'ih'),1),10,10);
```

My implementation of the kernel within the proxm function is:

```
...
case {'dist_histint','ih'}
    [m,d]=size(A);
    [n,d1]=size(B);
    if (d ~= d1)
        error('column length of A (%d) != column length of B (%d)\n',d,d1);
    end

    % With the MATLAB JIT compiler the trivial implementation turns out
    % to be the fastest, especially for large matrices.
    D = zeros(m,n);
    for i=1:m % m is number of samples of A 
        if (0==mod(i,1000)) fprintf('.'); end
        for j=1:n % n is number of samples of B
            D(i,j) = sum(min([A(i,:);B(j,:)]));%./max(A(:,i),B(:,j)));
        end            
    end
```

I need some matlab optimization for this code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get rid of that kernel loop to calculate `D` with this [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) based [`vectorized`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) approach -

```
D = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@min,A,permute(B,[3 2 1])),2))
```

Or avoid `squeeze` with this modification -

```
D = sum(bsxfun(@min,permute(A,[1 3 2]),permute(B,[3 1 2])),3)
```

If the calculations of `D` involve `max` instead of `min`, just replace `@min` with `@max` there.

---

**Explanation:** The way `bsxfun` works is that it does *expansion* on singleton dimensions and performs the operation as listed with `@` inside its call. Now, this expansion is basically how one achieves vectorized solutions that replace for-loops. By `singleton dimensions` in arrays, we mean dimensions of `1` in them.

In many cases, singleton dimensions aren't already present and for vectorization with `bsxfun`, we need to create `singleton dimensions`. One of the tools to do so is with [`permute`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html). That's basically all about the way vectorized approach stated earlier would work.

Thus, your kernel code -

```
...
case {'dist_histint','ih'}
    [m,d]=size(A);
    [n,d1]=size(B);
    if (d ~= d1)
        error('column length of A (%d) != column length of B (%d)\n',d,d1);
    end

    % With the MATLAB JIT compiler the trivial implementation turns out
    % to be the fastest, especially for large matrices.
    D = zeros(m,n);
    for i=1:m % m is number of samples of A 
        if (0==mod(i,1000)) fprintf('.'); end
        for j=1:n % n is number of samples of B
            D(i,j) = sum(min([A(i,:);B(j,:)]));%./max(A(:,i),B(:,j)));
        end            
    end
```

reduces to -

```
...
case {'dist_histint','ih'}
    [m,d]=size(A);
    [n,d1]=size(B);
    if (d ~= d1)
        error('column length of A (%d) != column length of B (%d)\n',d,d1);
    end
    D = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@min,A,permute(B,[3 2 1])),2))
    %// OR D = sum(bsxfun(@min,permute(A,[1 3 2]),permute(B,[3 1 2])),3)
```

I am assuming the line: `if (0==mod(i,1000)) fprintf('.'); end` isn't important to the calculations as it does printing of some message.

Comment: I could not remove the loop but using the [bsxfun](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to calculate the mins got great improvement. finaly: D(i,j) = sum(bsxfun(@min,a(i,:),b(j,:))). thanks

Comment: @user3799302 What do you mean , you could not remove the loop? The code posted in this answer to calculate D is the replacement of the two nested loops you have in the kernel with : `for i=1:m` and `for j=1:n` being the two loops.

Comment: @user3799302 Did my earlier comment make sense?

Comment: It does work, but I still do not understand why. That is my job. Thanks again

Comment: @user3799302 Check out the edited explanations if they make sense to you?